# Host symfony app on plesk obsidian

Tags: ubuntu, php, plesk, symfony

Anyone was able to successfully run symfony application on the plesk environment already?

I'm new to management of plesk, until now i was configuring vhosts by my self, with use Apache / Nginx. I just moved most of my Wordpress Websites to the plesk without an issue, i was able to run also Laravel 5.7 Project, without a single problem. But somehow symfony project is causing me some troubles.

I've read about that symfony 4 requires PHP 7.1. I've tried to run it on every single possible PHP version from 7.0 to 7.4 (fpm / cgi). I am using Plesk 18 Obsidian.

I just unpacked the project files in the home directory of my domain inside of folder named Symfony and made an symbolic link to the PUBLIC folder as httpdocs, but it doesn't worked, it always show 403 page.

Edit:
I also tried to unpack it directly in httpdocs folder, and in the hosting settings change root directory to /httpdocs/public, but then it keeps asking me about username in password, like it was pasword protected area.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the symlink resulting in a 403. Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was deploying Symfony wiith Deployer to a Plesk environment. It was NOT adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` (it is not necessary), rather setting my file permissions correctly in the directory structure of the deploy path:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

Or, in a Deployer task:

```php
desc('Change Files And Folder Permissions');
task('deploy:permissions', function () {
    run('find {{ deploy_path }} -type d -exec chmod --silent 0755 {} +');
    run('find {{ deploy_path }} -type f -exec chmod --silent 0644 {} +');
});
```

The error I had was a little cryptic (`AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs`). I was blinded by "symbolic link not allowed", but the problem was the "link target not accessible" part.